# Jersey FormDataBodyPart getValueAs causes "Entity instance does not contain the unconverted content."

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-client

I need to construct a FormDataBodyPart object manually and then shortly afterwards I need to convert that to another object using getValueAs. Like so:

Early:

```
FormDataBodyPart fdbp= new FormDataBodyPart("{\"category\":\"Stormware\"}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE); 
fdbp.setName("theName");
```

Later:

```
Attachment metaData = fdbp.getValueAs(Attachment.class);
```

Hitting the later line of code gives the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Entity instance does not contain the unconverted content.
at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.BodyPart.getEntityAs(BodyPart.java:291)
at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataBodyPart.getValueAs(FormDataBodyPart.java:315)
```

I'm not sure how I can create the FormDataBodyPart object such that getValueAs works properly.

Comment: make sure you have the field name "category" in Attachment class

Comment: Can confirm that the Attachment class does have this field and that the field value is valid for the type.

Comment: You can't do that. When you create the `FornDataBodyPart` yourself, it is meant to be an "outgoing" entity. You are trying to treat it as an "incoming" entity by using `getValueAs()`. An "outgoing" entity means that you are preparing to send it out in a request from a client. An "incoming" entity is one where it's either a method parameter of a resource method or a deserialized entity from a client response.

Answer (score 2):

I could find a solution in proper way, but my workaround looks like this: this code is in actual service implementation.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T> T getEntityAs(BodyPart bodyPart, Class<T> clazz) {
        try {
            // used for runtime
            return bodyPart.getEntityAs(clazz);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // used for tests
            return (T) bodyPart.getEntity();
        }
}
```

Regards.